# Choosing the number of units in a layer of a neural network for conic data distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have created a dataset of containing all points contained in a circle labelled as 0 and all points outside it as 1. I wanted to teach a simple neural network if it can learn the binary classification problem.

Now, I have dealt with XOR problem. That inspired me to use two hidden layers. Since circle is a conic like a pair of straight lines used in XOR problem, this makes some sense. Otherwise I'd have gone for single hidden layer. No issues there. I am having trouble interpreting the use case of number of units/neurons in each layer.

Obviously, I have experimented thusly.

```
def layer_experiment(first=2,second=1):
  print("Layers' count : ",first," ",second)
  # create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(first, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(second, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  # Fit the model
  model.fit(data[:4000,[0,1]],data[:4000,2],epochs=30, batch_size=20, verbose=0)
  scores = model.evaluate(data[4000:,:2], data[4000:,2])
  print("Scores : ",scores)
  predictions = model.predict_proba(data[4000:,:2])
  # predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
  predictions = [[migrate(x[0])] for x in predictions]
  dd = np.append(data[4000:,:2],predictions,axis=-1)
  df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
  fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df,hue=2,aspect=1.61)
  fg.map(plt.scatter,0,1).add_legend()
```

I was wondering why the change of different parameters, caused change in plots or more specifically, hyperplanes separating the data.
More code here : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14HYdrUxvc5REUdToFkfZQxElPq_0l7-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Five unique points define a conic intersecting the plane (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) so if each neuron models one the two co-ordinates of the point you could try 10.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't get the answer, the part after the link. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: To model the conic you need five points in the plane. Each point has two coordinates. 5x2 = 10 which is the number of free parameters needed to define the conic (excluding the possibility of collinearity). Thus 10 might be a good bet for the number of neurons appropriate for your hidden layer.

Comment: Ok, but for which layer? Considering single hidden layer, that may well be the case. I'm asking what's the number in first one vs the number in second one?

Comment: Probably the first one, maybe try (10*9)/2 = 45 in the second. That's the problem with NNs though, there aren't really any hard and fast rules - without an awful lot of analysis (have your read "Perceptrons" by Minsky and Pappert?) its not very easy to be sure of very much at all. Sorry about that. Looks like you have a model there though, why not try some out and see? I'd be interested to know what actually works.

Comment: Actually, single hidden layer with 10 units succeeded. To be honest, any number between 7-11 gave nearly same accuracy, 9 is the best value as it minimized loss and improved accuracy drastically. I still don't know why though. I updated the colab notebook for your viewing. I'm guessing 45 might be an overkill in that regard. I'll keep looking until I can interpret this thing.

Comment: I think its because there are 10 parameters but also a planar constraint so in the end there are just 9 degrees of freedom. Good that it worked, quite an interesting result theoretically. Hey now you can upvote my answer ;)

Comment: I've updated the notebook. Here are my observations. sigmoid(ax+by+c) is essentially a line with zero or one bend/corner. A weighted sum of them contorts the line into convex shapes as needed, in this example. It depends on data as we all expect as it determines weights and what not. The relu in intermediate does a better job at decision boundary enclosure than sigmoid but it's more polygonal as opposed to curvy nature of relu decision boundary.

Comment: As far as number of nodes are concerned. Yes, five point theory is correct. We just need one layer for most looped conics. Any number more than 5 gives more accuracy. 8 or 9 is still the best but 10+ is an overkill/overfitting. This works for any shape in conics - ellipse (8), circle (6 to 8), parabola (6 to 8), hyperbola (7). As far as multiple layers are concerned, it gets tricky as nested functions are now in picture. Still working on it.Updated the notebook for everyone to refer. Removed ellipse and hyperbola though. One can modify circle one to get there if you know parametric equations.